# How to create an easy visualization of timestamps in R

Tags: r, timestamp

I have a series of timestamps as following:

```
 > df$EndDate
  [1] 15/03/2020 19:41 16/03/2020 12:06 16/03/2020 15:41 16/03/2020 16:06 16/03/2020 19:09
  [6] 16/03/2020 19:15 16/03/2020 19:17 16/03/2020 19:25 16/03/2020 19:27 16/03/2020 19:36
```

I would like to be able to create a graph that helps understand the procceding of when the events occured, something like that:[image: example]

how can I create in in R with this type of data? any help would assist me. thank you!

Comment: You need to define your events, e.g. when the derivative is zero, and then apply a label to each with the value of X. If you could provide any more information on the event you are after and where the timestamp should occur that would be most helpful.

Comment: the event is a survey being completed, and the stamp is the moment it was completed. I'd like to make a graph where one could see how many surveys were completed as time went on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. 1. Convert Enddate to Datetime format. 2. Count by Endate. 3. Sort (arrange) and compute cumulated sum. 4. Plot.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  EndDate = c("15/03/2020 19:41", "16/03/2020 12:06", "16/03/2020 15:41", "16/03/2020 16:06", "16/03/2020 19:09",
"16/03/2020 19:15", "16/03/2020 19:17", "16/03/2020 19:25", "16/03/2020 19:27", "16/03/2020 19:36"))

df %>% 
  mutate(EndDate = as.POSIXct(EndDate, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz=Sys.timezone())) %>% 
  count(EndDate) %>% 
  arrange(EndDate) %>% 
  mutate(n_cum = cumsum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(EndDate, n_cum)) +
  geom_line(color = "red") +
  labs(x = "time", y = "# of event")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>